# MariaDB R/W should be available only to Application like flask

Tags: mariadb

I want mariadb R/W should only be available to the application like FLASK.
And no other application should access it?

Is there any specific configuration for this?Please let me know

Comment: @Rick James :Seeking your answer?

Comment: Thanks i got answer for this using pysql connection with the username and password we can do this